# What is the function doing in the python list?

Tags: python

```
    char_set = [False for _ in range(128)]
    for char in string:
       val = ord(char)
       if char_set[val]:
           # Char already found in string
           return False
       char_set[val] = True
```

I'm trying to decipher this code but don't understand what char_set is doing? The part inside the list is confusing.

Comment: Note: When initializing a `list` of the same immutable object many times over, it's faster/simpler to do `char_set = [False] * 128`. Key point: Only do this for `list`s of _immutable_ objects (`bool`, numerics, `tuple`, `frozenset`, `str`, `bytes`, what have you), don't do it for mutable objects because you'll end up with a bunch of references to the same mutable object, which is rarely what you want (changing one changes all of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[False for _ in range(128)]` is a list comprehension that will return a list of 128 `False`s. In other words, `char_set` will be `[False, False, ...]` with 128 `False`. The `_` represents a throwaway value (a value which is created by the `range()` function, but that the program does not need to do anything with. In this case, `_` is the  number representing the iterations of the `range()` function (i.e., `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.).